# Python and how to set encoding to utf-8?

Tags: python, encoding, words

I'm struggling with encoding of charaters in Python. I have script which takes article from website which is full of special language characters and I'm opening a external file with common words, a `txt` file which is saved to `utf-8` and also has word with special characters. Part of code where I wanna set up a encoding looks like this:

```
def getArticleText(webtext):
articletext = ""
soup = BeautifulSoup(webtext)
for tag in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"dr_article"}):
    for element in tag.find_all("p"):
        articletext += element.contents[0]
    return articletext

def getArticle(url):
htmltext = gethtml.getHtmlText(url)
return getArticleText(htmltext)

def getKeywords(articletext):
common = open("word_rank/comon.txt").read().split('\n')
word_dict = {}
word_list = articletext.lower().split()
for word in word_list:
    if word not in common :
        if word not in word_dict:
            word_dict[word] = 1
        if word in word_dict:
            word_dict[word] += 1
print sorted(word_dict.items(),key=lambda(k,v):(v,k),reverse=True)
```

Now I don't have problem with print of that whole `articletext`. It prints out those special characters in a right way.

My problem are that keywords defined in `getKeywords` definition, they get printed out in that way as in example:

```
(u'\u0161elteru', 2), (u'\u010ditateljice', 2),
(u'\u017eeli,', 2), (u'\u0161tekat', 2),
```

and so on...

How can I set up a encoding of that keywords so that it would display words in proper way?

Comment: Probably BeautifulSoup encoded utf-8 characters, find decoding method.

Answer (score 1):

Use [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode)

Example usage:

```
t = u"\u5317\u4EB0"
unidecode( '%s' % (t,) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've setted up `.decode('utf-8')` in `common = open("word_rank/comon.txt").read().split('\n')` right after `.read()` and it worked. Just what I need :D. Thanks anyway guys!